# Recarga de página tras pulsar el botón y mantener tab activa con jQuery

Tags: jquery, bootstrap

Tengo una vista en mi web con tabs (bootstrap) con diferente información. En la tab3 necesito que se refresque la página para que recargue una serie de datos, pero que se mantenga esa tab seleccionada (solo en ese caso). Si por ejemplo estamos trabajando en la tab1 y refresca el usuario manualmente, no quiero que se mantenga activa la tab3, sino la tab1 (que es la principal).

```
<ul id="myTabs" class="nav nav-tabs">
 <li class=""><a href="#tab1" data-tongle="tab">Tab1</a></li>
 <li class=""><a href="#tab2" data-tongle="tab">Tab2</a></li>
 <li class="active"><a href="#tab3" data-tongle="tab">Tab3</a></li>
 <li class=""><a href="#tab4" data-tongle="tab">Tab4</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="miboton">
    <button type="button">Recargar datos</button>
</div>
```

El código Javascript que tengo por el momento es:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    //Esta tab se mantiene como principal siempre y solo quiero 
    //que se mantenga cuando se pulsa el botón y se hace el reload
    jQuery('.nav-tabs a[href="#tab3"]').tab('show');

    jQuery('#miboton button[type="button"]').on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var id_input = jQuery('#requestId').val();
        viewAhorroData(id_input);
    });

    var viewAhorroData = function(itemId)
    {
        if(document.formvalidator.isValid(document.id('my-form')))
        {                   
            location.reload();

        }
        else
        {
            alert('Form invalid!');
        }

    }

});
```

Mi problema es que digo que se seleccione la tab3 justo cuando carga la página completa (tras `document.ready`). ¿Cómo puedo discriminar esto? Que solo recargue la página cuando se pulsa el botón y tras esto se mantenga la tab3 como activa. Gracias!

Comment: Para ese tipo de comportamiento la mejor opción sería usar una llamada AJAX en vez de una recarga. Lanzas la llamada AJAX para recuperar los datos que necesitas, los recuperas y los inyectas en el HTML con Javascript. Para hacer lo que quieres mediante una recarga de página, tendrías que guardar en algún lugar persistente (DB, variables de sesión...) la tab en la que se encontraba el usuario en el momento de dar al botón que lanza la recarga. Luego ya podrías cargar de nuevo la página recuperando ese valor para usarlo ya sea desde el lado del cliente o del servidor.

Comment: lo que dijo el colega es la mejor opcion, pero si queres seguir usando el metodo que estas usando tendrias que probar a hacer algo por el estilo : cambiar el `window.reload()` por un `window.location.href = window.location.href + "#tab3"` (ejemplo)

Answer (score 1):

Si usas localStorage y el evento onchange de los tabs de bootstrap puedes obtener lo que deseas intenta con este ejemplo y me dices que tal

```
<ul id="myTabs" class="nav nav-tabs">
 <li class=""><a href="#tab1" data-tongle="tab">Tab1</a></li>
 <li class=""><a href="#tab2" data-tongle="tab">Tab2</a></li>
 <li class=""><a href="#tab3" data-tongle="tab">Tab3</a></li>
 <li class=""><a href="#tab4" data-tongle="tab">Tab4</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="miboton">
    <button type="button">Recargar datos</button>
</div>

jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
      var target = $(e.target).attr("href") // activated tab
      localStorage.setItem('activeTab', target);
    });

    if(localStorage.getItem('activeTab')){
        $('a[href="'+localStorage.getItem('activeTab')+'"]').parent().addClass('active');
    } else {
        $('#myTabs li:first').addClass('active');
    }


    jQuery('#miboton button[type="button"]').on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var id_input = jQuery('#requestId').val();
        viewAhorroData(id_input);
    });

    var viewAhorroData = function(itemId)
    {
        if(document.formvalidator.isValid(document.id('my-form')))
        {                   
            location.reload();

        }
        else
        {
            alert('Form invalid!');
        }

    }

});
```